# How to solve "Index was outside the bounds of the array"?

Tags: c#, .net

i have written a piece of code where i am dividing two decimals as below. when the value of z in the code is like 2.33, then it works fine but when the value of z in the code is like 2.0, in this line "long secondValue = Convert.ToInt64(values[1]);" it is crashing as "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

```
  result_lstCatalogcount.CountofItems = Convert.ToInt32(item1.itemcount);
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(item1.itemcount);
            double y = qs.Ipp;
            double z = x / y;
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(z);
            //double value = 2635.215;
            var values = z.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
            int firstValue = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);

            long secondValue = Convert.ToInt64(values[1]);
            if(secondValue > 1)
            {
                result_lstCatalogcount.Pagination = firstValue + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result_lstCatalogcount.Pagination = firstValue;
            }
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: debug through and look what is inside `values`. I bet it´s not what you expect...

Answer (score 3):

The `ToString` of 2.0 will just be "2" with no period, so when you split you get an array with only one item at index 0.  You can check the size of the array to handle this.

```
int firstValue = values.Length > 1 ? Convert.ToInt64(values[1]) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to parse `values[1]` into a `long` without actually checking if there's a value in index 1.  If the number is an `integer` like `2` as your example, then `values[0]` I would expect to contain `2`, and `value[1]` would likely not exist.

You need to check that your index actually exists before attempting to convert them into not nullable objects.

You could do this with something as simple as

```
double secondValue = 0;
if (values.Length > 1)
{
    secondValue = Convert.ToInt64(values[1]);
}
```

Or something to that effect.

Comment: `value[1]` is not `null`, it just doesn't exist because the array only has one item, thus the out of bounds exception.

Comment: why the downvote?  It's in effect the same answer as the answer that has +2? (Granted, one of them is mine)

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I think it was before you made changes based on my comment.

Comment: @juharr nah it occurred within the last 10 minutes - edit was 40 minutes ago :(